# Strange exception when a text field becomes first responder

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, textfield

I have inherited a project and have to remake a part of it which deals with contacts. I'm using a third party library `THContactPicker` but when adding the contact picker programatically (which has a text field in the view) the text field  causes an exception

> [NSBigMutableString replaceCharactersInRange:withString:]: nil argument

when becoming first responder. I have tried adding any other object that has text input programatically and it shows the same exception when they become first responder. If I add them through storyboard they do not show this exception. What can be causing this issue?

P.S. there aren't any text related delegates in view controller

Answer (score 1):

This exception occurs because you accidentally try to `append a nil argument` to an NSMutableString.

NSBigMutableString is the backing store for an `NSTextStorage/NSMutableAttributedString`, so
if you ever call `-[NSBigMutableString replaceCharactersInRange:withString:]` (where aString is nil), this is the exception
that's raised.

Comment: Ty for your answer, I don't understand how these 2 could be related and how would any text input try to append a nil argument on first responder? I don't see -[NSBigMutableString replaceCharactersInRange:withString:] method being called anywhere in the project either.

Comment: Are you or THContactPicker doing anything in your text field's delegate methods?(textFieldShouldBeginEditing/textFieldDidBeginEditing)

Comment: The problem seems to occur in the whole application, on every view controller if a  text field or anything with text input is added programatically it shows that exception when becoming first responder.